# optimal k-step ahead for hourly ARIMA model

Tags: time-series, arima

I am doing an analysis using ARIMA for Hourly orders forecasting . Is there optimal k-step ahead for hourly ARIMA model ?

Comment: Number of steps ahead you want to forecast is determined by the business needs of the problem you are trying to forecast.

Answer (score 1):

Hourly predictions may depend on

1. what day of the week it is
2. what month your are in
3. what level changes have occurred
4. what trend changes have occurred
5. what days of the month exhibit statistically usual effect
6. what recent activity has been  *arima structure"
7. what week of the month you are in
8. holiday effects before, on and after
9. long weekend effects

Thus your answer really depends in what your data knows and what you need to find out.